# How can I build model data?

Tags: reactjs

I was asked to create a mini amazon web app and as model data, I was told to use the below code. const items is products sold in the mini amazon and const promotion is a seperate data for all promotion each user get. Where do I store itemsAvailable.js and promotion.js so that I can fetch those in react components?

```
 // itemsAvailable.js
const items = [
  {
    id: '123',
    title: 'product1',
    coverImage: 'public.jpg',
    price: 20,
    score: 20,
  },
  {
    id: '123123',
    title: 'product2',
    coverImage: 'public2.jpg',
    price: 30,
    score: 30,

  }, 
];


// promotion.js
const promotion = [
  {
    type: 'sale',
    title: '30%',
    rate: 30,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `state`,

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        item: [{
            id: '123',
            title: 'product1',
            coverImage: 'public.jpg',
            price: 20,
            score: 20,
          },
          {
           id: '123123',
           title: 'product2',
           coverImage: 'public2.jpg',
           price: 30,
           score: 30,
          } 
       ],
       promotion: [{
           type: 'sale',
           title: '30%',
           rate: 30,
          }
       ]
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
{
    this.state.item.map((item)=>{
      <div>{item.id}</div>
      ....
    })
}
```

Likewise you can use `promotion` array.